# As a process child, how to know which file descriptor is parents

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, file-descriptor

I am attempting to write a program which forks and waits for his child to finish, then the child does some work on an input and then forks the same way it's parent does and so on.

Now, I know that forking copies to the child the array of file descriptors and that I should close the ones associated with the parent, but I can't figure out which are the parents. Do I need to give to my child it's parents pid?

I've been trying to wrap my head around it for the better part of an hour and I think I have some kind of a mind block because I can't come to a conclusion.

TL;DR: As a child process how do I know which file descriptors belong to my parent?

Comment: "*close the ones associated with the parent, but I can't figure out which are the parents.*" Why? You are writing the code.

Comment: Did you try the `getppid()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after the `fork` (and *before* any `exec` function) your child process has the same state as its parent process (except for the result of the `fork`, which is 0 only in the child). So *you know* what are the file descriptors, since you have coded the program running in parent&child. On Linux you might also read the `/proc/self/fd/` directory, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

You might close most file descriptors after the `fork` and before the `exec`; you could code something like

```
for (int fd=3; fd<64; fd++) (void) close(fd);
```

we are starting from 3 which is after `STDERR_FILENO` which is 2, and we are stopping arbitrarily at 64, and the cast to `(void)` on the `close` call means to the reader that we don't care about failing `close`.... Of course, if you have e.g. some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s to communicate between parent and child you'll be careful to avoid closing their relevant file descriptor(s).

<sup>(However, doing a closing loop like above is poor taste and old fashion)</sup>

In general, you'll be careful in your program to set the close-on-exec flag on most file descriptors (e.g. [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) on `F_SETFD` operation and `FD_CLOEXEC` flag, or directly [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) with `O_CLOEXEC`), then the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (done in most child processes after the `fork`) would close them.